# how do i pass a the input value of the textfield from some component to another component in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend

I am trying to pass the value of the text area from some component in reactjs to be used in another react component. the component value is stored in the first component in a `useState` hook so I want to access it in another component and run `map()` function around it . Is this possible in reactjs ? I don't want to put the whole thing in app.js because that is just plain HTML which I don't want. I want to use reactjs function components instead ?

**first component:**

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

function Firstcomp() {
  const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState(["hi there", "greetings"]);
  const reference = useRef();

  function sub(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setQuotes((old) => [reference.current.value, ...old]);
    console.log(quotes);

    return;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <h4>jon snow</h4>
          </div>

          <form onSubmit={sub}>
            <textarea
              type="textarea"
              ref={reference}
              placeholder="Type your tweet..."
            />
            <button type="submit">Tweet</button>
          </form>
          {quotes.map((item) => (
            <li key={item}>{item}</li>
          ))}
          {/* we can use card display taking item as prop where it 
            will do the job of filling the <p> in card entry */}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default Firstcomp;
```

**second component**

```
import React from "react";

function SecondComp(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.message}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Secondcomp;
```

Comment: Can you share what is the relationship between Firstcomp and SecondComp? Are they siblings, parent child, or are they completed unrelated?

Comment: You better see it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71381148/how-to-pass-input-value-to-another-react-component

Comment: they are compleatly unreleated but i want to use them both as in. use the first comp to write stuff and secondcomp uses the text value from firstcomp so I can have <p> tags printed with the values given in first comp. i can do the whole thing in app.js without components but I want to use components instead

Answer (score 0):

Use a global management state like Recoil, Redux ot Context

Comment: i have heared about redux but can you explain how would it help in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

export const UserContext = React.createContext();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value="Reed">
      <User />
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}

function User() {
  const value = React.useContext(UserContext);  
    
  return <h1>{value}</h1>;
}
```

on the exemple above we used useContext hook to provide a global variable "value", even its not declared directly in User component, but you can use it by calling the useContext hook.

in this exemple the return value in the user component is "Reed"